# form submit goes to wrong page in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I created a page which collect few information and when submit it loads to completely wrong page even though URL is correct.

Here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".ch1").change(function () {
            jQuery(".ch1").prop("checked", false);
            jQuery(this).prop("checked", true);
        });
        jQuery(".ch2").change(function () {
            jQuery(".ch2").prop("checked", false);
            jQuery(this).prop("checked", true);
        });
        jQuery("#tour_date").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            showOn: "button",
            buttonText: "Select Date",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
        });
    });
    function validateForm() {
        var children = jQuery("#child_cnt").val();
        var adlt_cnt = jQuery("#adlt_cnt").val();
        var tour_date = jQuery("#tour_date").val();
        if (children == "") {
            alert("Please enter No. of children");
            return false;
        }
        if (adlt_cnt == "") {
            alert("Please enter No. of adults");
            return false;
        }
        if (tour_date == "") {
            alert("Please enter tour date");
            return false;
        }
        if (!validateTripTypes()) {
            alert("Please select a trip type");
            return false;
        }
        if (!validateServices()) {
            alert("Please select a service");
            return false;
        }

    }
    function  validateTripTypes() {
        if (jQuery('.ch1:checked').length > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    function  validateServices() {
        if (jQuery('.ch2:checked').length > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
[vc_section][vc_column_text]

<form method="post" name="page1_form" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="[insert_php] bloginfo('url'); [/insert_php]/new-tour-booking-next2/">
    <label>No. of Children:</label> <input name="child_cnt" size="10" type="number" id="child_cnt"/>
    <label>No. of Adults:</label> <input name="adlt_cnt" id="adlt_cnt" size="10" type="number" />
    <label>Tour Date:</label> <input name="tour_date" id="tour_date" size="10" type="text" placeholder="Select Date"/>[/vc_column_text][/vc_section]

    [insert_php]
    $wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();
    $wp_session['child_cnt'] = 0;
    global $wpdb;
    $trip_types = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM jtb_trip_types WHERE status = %d", array(1))
    );
    [/insert_php]

    [vc_row][vc_column][vc_text_separator title="Type of Trip" title_align="separator_align_left"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_section][vc_column_text]
    [insert_php]
    $trip_type_list = "";
    foreach ($trip_types as $trip_type) {
    $trip_type_list .= '<input name="trip_type_list[]" size="10" type="checkbox" class="ch1" value="'.$trip_type->id.'" /><label>'.$trip_type->trip_type_name.'</label>
    ';
    }
    echo $trip_type_list;
    [/insert_php]

    [/vc_column_text][/vc_section][vc_row][vc_column][vc_text_separator title="Services" title_align="separator_align_left"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column][vc_column_text]
    <input name="services_list[]" size="10" type="checkbox" class="ch2" value="1"/> <label>Vehicles</label>
    <input name="services_list[]" size="10" type="checkbox" class="ch2" value="2"/> <label>Hotels</label>
    <input name="services_list[]" size="10" type="checkbox" class="ch2" value="3"/> <label>Both</label>

    [/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column][vc_btn title="Next" name="btn_next_form_1" type="submit" align="left"][/vc_column][/vc_row]

    [insert_php]
    //echo count($trip_types);
    [/insert_php]

    </<form>
```

It redirect to the correct URL. Which is this one http://www.jaudatravels.com/new-tour-booking-next2/

But it loads this page data even though URL is correct. http://www.jaudatravels.com/tours/

NB: This happens only when we submit the from through this page. http://www.jaudatravels.com/new-tour-booking/

Is there any reason for this behaviour?

Comment: check the page source if there are any other event handlers binding on that page to the same form?

Comment: The redirect is not handled by the form, it is handled by the server side form processing code

Comment: As @charlietfl said, your original URL may answer with redirect. You can check this in 'network' tab of browser dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your custom form & the right side search form both have been bind to a single submit event.
That is the reason the data getting loaded is not the one which you are expecting even though URL is correct because the URL is just to display the processing happens at the server side.

Solution:
**There is a syntax error in ending form:  `</<form>` rectify it**
Or Just remove that search widget & try.

And also always be careful about the form structure when form start there must not be any **div** or a **table** interruption like

```
<div>
<form>
<input type="text" name="my_input"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Or

```
<table>
<tr>
<form>
<th><td><input type="text" name="my_input"/></td></th>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

So always include entire element (like div Or table Or anything) within the form so that no interruptions happen.